# Profile section doesn't stretch well

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, mobile-web

If I put a single space into my About Me section (I don't want others to see *"This user has not filled their about me section yet"*), the mobile site will display my profile page incorrectly:

[image]

I also opened the profile page with filled About Me on my PC:

[image]

The width of profile section seems smaller than it should be.

Looks like empty About Me section just makes the bug evident on smartphones.

The main site and the app are not affected.